# Pattern find only one character of regex in group

Tags: java, regex

I have pattern compiled like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*((M+)\\W*(d+)).*");
```

And string:

```
String string = "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy";
```

matcher.group(2) returns only "M" but I want to get whole "MMMM" word. How can I do this using groups? I thought that M+ regex will handle this case. Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the first `.*` as non-greedy by adding `?` next to that `*`. NOte that `.*` is greedy which matches all the characters upto the last. So `.*(M+)` should capture only the last `M`, since all the chars which exists before `M` are matched by `.*`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?((M+)\\W*(d+)).*");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @KarpatQ - Upvoting is the best way of saying *thanks* without actually saying it.

Comment: Guys I had to wait 15 minutes to accept this answer, so I wanted only to say "thanks" before it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another way was to be as specific as possible in your regex. If you don't want to "eat up" an `M` in the beginning, you should specify that:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^M]*((M+)\\W*(d+)).*");
```

EDIT: According to [Jeffrey E.F. Friedl in his book "Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do) (chapter 7, section "A non-greedy construct vs. a negated character class") a negated character class should be preferred to non-greedy operators in most situations. This is a quotation of the last paragraph in the section on page 227 of my (older) **printed** edition of the book.

> The non-greedy constructs are without a doubt the most powerful Perl5
>   additions to the regex flavor, but you must use them with care. A
>   non-greedy `.*?` is almost never a reasonable substitute for `[^...]*`
>   — one might be proper for a particular situation, but due to their
>   vastly different meaning, the other is likely incorrect.